# Windows - unload dll from suspended process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I injected dll into other processes to hooking APIs.
And then, unloading dlls from other processes to change dll file.
But, suspended processes dll doesn't unload till restart.
So I can't change dll file.
I tried something in code level to avoid this situation.

**1. Restart process - not work**

**2. Unload module - not work**

**3. Kill process - work, but have risk**

Is there any other way to unloading dll from suspended process?

Comment: No expert, but: unloading a DLL requires changes to the process, a suspended process cannot be changed. Just saying, might be wrong.

Comment: what mean unload dll at all ? what if another code call function from this dll after this. what if some callback in dll active ?

Comment: Not sure about the internals, but since [processes are initialized in-process](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131) it would seem reasonable that unloading a module would require coöperation from within the process as well. A suspended process doesn't coöperate.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need/want to unload a dll? What dll?

Comment: @IInspectable Unloading a DLL requires code to run (for example, to run the DLL's `PROCESS_DETACH` handler).